# Mês e Ano Datepicker

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Seguindo a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137439) desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974394/bootstrap-datepicker-months-and-years-only), eu tentei implementar em um campo texto de um modal esse mesmo comando, mas vem deformado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script>
  $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
  format: "mm-yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});
```

Estou tentando colocar apenas mês e ano do calendário

```
05/2017
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso parece muito um problema de CSS. De duas uma:

- Ocorreu um conflito entre o CSS do componente datepicker que você utiliza (que não é nativo do bootstrap) e o CSS do bootstrap ou do seu site. Note que o componente que você utiliza aparentemente teve sua última atualização em 2013, enquanto o Bootstrap continuou a evoluir desde então.
- Faltou incluir o CSS do componente datepicker.

Para verificar isso, utilize as ferramentas de desenvolvimento do navegador (geralmente acessíveis através da tecla F12). Verifique que regras de formatação são aplicadas no site que utiliza de exemplo. Veja se as mesmas regras são aplicadas na sua própria página. Assim você pode verificar quais regras a sua página deixou de seguir, localizá-las, e incluir ou ajustar o CSS conforme suas necessidades.

Caso verifique que o conflito é de versão (i.e.: você utiliza bootstrap versão 3.0.0, não suportado pelo datepicker da Eyecon), você pode passar a utilizar uma versão mais antiga do boostrap, ou procurar outro componente de seleção de datas. O [datepicker da UX Solutions](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) é livre e compatível com a versão 3.0.0.

Comment: Estou chamando o datepicker.min.css

Comment: era isso mesmo. Meu bootstrap estava muito evoluido, peguei o bootstrap do plugin e funcionou